# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when linking c project

Tags: c, xcode, compiler-construction, linker

I try to compile the [picoc](http://code.google.com/p/picoc/) project into xcode. No external libraries, just .c and .h files that I imported in the Command Line Tool C project.

All .c files compile without issue, but when XCode is linking, I get these messages:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_BasicIOInit", referenced from:
      _PicocInitialise in platform.o
  "_CStdOut", referenced from:
      _PrintSourceTextErrorLine in platform.o
      _PlatformVPrintf in platform.o
  "_MathFunctions", referenced from:
      _IncludeInit in include.o
  "_MathSetupFunc", referenced from:
      _IncludeInit in include.o
  "_PicocPlatformScanFile", referenced from:
      _IncludeFile in include.o
  ...
```

The command giving the error is the following:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -v -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk -L/Users/laurent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pico-dhfwbamkhiyphjcwuncbwjsyjlax/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/laurent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pico-dhfwbamkhiyphjcwuncbwjsyjlax/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/laurent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pico-dhfwbamkhiyphjcwuncbwjsyjlax/Build/Intermediates/Pico.build/Debug/Pico.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Pico.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -o /Users/laurent/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Pico-dhfwbamkhiyphjcwuncbwjsyjlax/Build/Products/Debug/Pico

The Pico.LinkFileList file contains properly the list of all necessary .o files.

As all the unfound functions are in the properly compiled .c files (and compiled as .o), what should I do to avoid these errors ?
Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to show the commands that generated the linker errors?

Comment: Check if all c files are added to the target ("Target Membership" checkbox in the file inspector).

Comment: Martin: Yes they all are.

Answer (score 1):

Those symbols are in `clibrary.c`; you must have missed it from the list of source files to compile.

Your next question will doubtless be about libraries to link the executable with, and to solve that I would suggest you look at the `Makefile`.

Comment: It was there, the issue was finally due to some #ifdef that were excluding the functions to be compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Adding Pico to the Target Dependencies list worked for me after the same situation. (from Pico i mean the xcode project folder from where we have created library)

reference :
**https://github.com/bulldog2011/pico**

Answer (score 0):

In case it can help someone, I found out that some #ifdef commands were excluding the functions to be compiled.

Comment: If you want to help people, don't you agree that you should provide a bit more detail than some vague reference to something unspecified being set/missing? Just sayin...